# Meteor, Bootstrap-3, mobile responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an app to work nicely with a mobile browser, having got it working well on a normal desktop.  I'm just starting out on the responsive layout stuff so am a bit of a newbie here.

I have the bootstrap nav-bar working down to 768px as shown here
[image: Above 768px]

but at 768px and below it does this

[image: Below 768px]

So, I'm obviously missing something in my css but have NO idea how to get the menu to stack as I thought it would automagically at the mobile browser sizes (isn't that what bootstrap is meant to do for me?).

The code being used to generate the menu is

```
<template name="header">
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'request'}}">Make a request</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'pack'}}">Packing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'admin'}}">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {{>loginButtons}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Thanks guys, my lack of understanding is glaring I assume.

Peter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the following in your navbar markup;

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
```

See the documentation on the navbar [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap will do what you are expecting it to, given you use the right tags and classes. For the navbar, you've missed `<div class="navbar-header">` which holds the toggle-button to show/hide the menu on smaller viewports. The code looks like:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The `navbar1` is the `id` from your `.navbar-collapse` div.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar1">
```

You can also add an anchor tag within the div for adding any logo or brand name:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo/Company name here</a>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/OTmGgX2yo9)** *(Click on the mobile icon to see it in mobile view)*

Comment: @PeterNUnn By experimenting, I guess.